# Accessing computed properties of child components in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What's the proper way to access computed properties of child components? Below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve (also available on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/957zhqdz/5/)):

```js
const FoobarWidget = {
    template: '<li>a: <input type="text" v-model="value.a" style="width:2em;"> b: <input type="text" v-model="value.b" style="width:2em;"> sum: {{this.sum}} <button @click="die">x</button></li>',
    props: {
        value: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        sum() {
            const s = Number(this.value.a) + Number(this.value.b)
            // WARNING eslint - vue:no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
            this.value.sum = s;
            return s;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        die() {
            this.$emit('die');
        }
    }
};

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        foobars: [{
            a: '5',
            b: '6'
        }],
    },
    components: {
        FoobarWidget,
    },
    computed: {
        myJson() {
            return JSON.stringify(this.foobars, null, 2);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addNew() {
            this.foobars.push({
                a: '1',
                b: '2'
            });
        },
        foobarDead(index) {
            this.foobars.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addNew()">add foobar</button>
  <h3>Foobars</h3>
  <ul>
    <foobar-widget v-for="(foobar, index) in foobars" :key="index" @die="foobarDead(index)" v-model="foobars[index]"/>
  </ul>
  <h3>JSON</h3>
  <pre>{{myJson}}</pre>
</div>
```

As one can see after trying this example, it mostly works - except it doesn't reflect the changes very well in parent component (generated JSON) after changing the values in child components (a, b, and computed sum).

The question seems similar to [SO: Computed property on child component props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950930/computed-property-on-child-component-props), however OP of that question had a computed value doing string formatting, making use of Vue filters a good solution. This is not the case here - the `sum()` computed property can be an arbitrary function, which is needed to be accessed both in parent and in child components.

The way I did it above, by modifying the prop object by adding a `sum` property to it when it's recomputed is definitely not the right way to do it, hence my question. Not only it works wonkily, but it also produces an ESLint warning (the `WARNING` comment in code above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you're taking the wrong approach here. If you want a property that is the sum of the values on the object, add that property to the object, not to the component.

Here is an example.

```js
const FoobarWidget = {
  template: '<li>a: <input type="text" v-model="value.a" style="width:2em;"> b: <input type="text" v-model="value.b" style="width:2em;"> sum: {{value.sum}} <button @click="die">x</button></li>',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    die() {
      this.$emit('die');
    }
  }
};

const foo = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
  // define your property here
  get sum() {
    return +this.a + +this.b
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foobars: [foo],
  },
  components: {
    FoobarWidget,
  },
  methods: {
    addNew() {
      this.foobars.push({
        a: '1',
        b: '2',
        get sum() {
          return +this.a + +this.b;
        }
      });
    },
    foobarDead(index) {
      this.foobars.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="addNew()">add foobar</button>
  <h3>Foobars</h3>
  <ul>
    <foobar-widget v-for="(foobar, index) in foobars" :key="index" @die="foobarDead(index)" v-model="foobars[index]" />
  </ul>
  <h3>JSON</h3>
  <pre>{{foobars}}</pre>
</div>
```

Using this approach you never need to access the computed property of the component.

Comment: I ran your example and it doesn't seem to work (you are also missing the method definition in freshly pushed objects) - also, don't you lose the reactivity vue provides by abandoning computed properties and using regular object methods instead?

Comment: @Zaroth Which part doesn't work exactly? Seems to work fine to me. And no.

Comment: Child component doesn't display `sum` correctly - probably because the `{{this.sum}}` part in child template needs to be changed, to `{{value.sum()}}` possibly.

Comment: @Zaroth Yep I missed that one. Should be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your parent doesn't update is that you're [adding a property to an object, which Vue doesn't detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Instead of

```
    sum() {
        const s = Number(this.value.a) + Number(this.value.b)
        // WARNING eslint - vue:no-side-effects-in-computed-properties
        this.value.sum = s;
        return s;
    }
```

You would do

```
sum() {
    const s = Number(this.value.a) + Number(this.value.b)
    this.$set(this.value, 'sum', s);
    return s;
}
```

Notwithstanding the code smell of side effects in a computed, and updating values in a prop, which suggests you ought to be doing something differently.